# Difficulty following Lang's argument, Example 7 of Ch. 6, Sec. 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, proof-explanation

I've been trying to follow an example given by Lang in his Algebra text in which he computes the Galois group of $x^5 - x - 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (page 274). In particular, he factors the polynomial as $(x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + x^2 + 1) \pmod 2$, and then concludes that the Galois group must contain the product of a 2-cycle and a 3-cycle. Is this a special case of some general result I should know? If so, is there a proof of the fact in Lang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what edition of Lang: the 3rd? Anyway, the result Lang is implicitly using here is Prop. 2.8 p.344 VII-2 (3rd ed.), or Theorem 2.9 p.345 VII-2 (3rd. ed), or Prop. 15 p.248 IX-2 (1st ed.) I see in the 3rd ed., on p.274, right above your example he states the result you need, and refers to Theorem 2.9.

The basic idea is that you have a polynomial with integer coefficients $f(x)$ and you've reduced it mod $p$. Now $\pi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is an epimorphism. It seems plausible you could use $\pi$ to "pull back" automorphisms of extension fields of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ to automorphisms of extension fields of $\mathbb{Q}$. That is, if the $\mathbb{Q}$-extension field comes from $f(x)$, and the $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-extension field comes from $f(x)$ reduced mod $p$. Theorem 2.9 is a precise statement of what actually holds.